# How to convert string array into custom nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, object

I am trying to convert a string array into single nested object suggest a best way to do that,

For example, If I had a single element in an array

Input:

```
var keys = ["A"];
```

It should be like this,

Output:

```
{
    and: {
        tags: {
            contains: "A"
        }
    }
}
```

And if I add a second element for example,

Input:

```
var keys = ["A","B"];
```

It should add as a nested object like this,

Output:

```
{
    and: {
        tags: {
            contains: "A"
        },
        and: {
            tags: {
                contains: "B"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. What have you tried already for iterating the array and building the result object?

Comment: @DrewReese I have tried various solutions, and searched alot on this topic but couldn't get any actual solution so, I have asked this question if I get the answer it would benefit rest of the beginners who is also searching for the same solution, if you know the solution answer that or else skip this question no need to be rude! if everyone replied like this for your doubts you will not be in the positon where you are now.
try to be kind or skip the question.

Comment: Being upfront about what SO is about isn't being rude, sorry you feel that way though. I was trying to be kind. I'm also trying to help curate the site. As I said though, this site isn't for writing the code for you, you have to put in an honest effort, and if you have a specific issue, we can help with that.

Comment: The purpose of stackoverflow is to share our knowledge, when i am stuck in this issue for so long i have just asked if anybody can help and people who actually familiar with this issue helped. you can see it below, but just replying like this doesn't help anyone. everyone learn from others, You too.

Comment: I just asked for you to show us what you've tried mate, it's standard procedure not a personal attack. You have your fish for a day now, best of luck to you on your future endeavors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use [`Array.reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) function(*Thanks Drew Reese's suggestion*):

```js
const nest = arr => arr.reduceRight((acc, cur) => ({ and: { tags: { contains: cur }, ...acc } }), {});

console.log(nest(['A']));
console.log(nest(['A', 'B']));
console.log(nest(['A', 'B', 'C']));
```

Comment: Check out [reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) and you'll not need to reverse the array first (`reverse` mutates the array in-place so might not be ideal for use in React).

Comment: @DrewReese Woah, it actually is a thing! Thanks for pointing out!